# Ping Pong Pi - A Ping Pong score and serving manager

Tags: python, python-2.x, linux, raspberry-pi

I have spent a few hours on this code, but think it could be improved a bit. It requires eSpeak to be installed to run the speech synthesis, but the voice can be toggled on or off using the `togglevoice` command. This was created for Python 2.7.3.

My major concerns are the fluctuations of the use of `global` to define global variables, the re-use of the variable `n` in functions and readability of the `d` array. It currently works fine on a Raspberry Pi running the latest version of Raspbian.

```
import os
def talk(n):
    if voice_mode == 1:
        os.system("espeak -ven+m3 '" + n + "' 2>/dev/null")
    else:
        print n

def print_score(n):
    if n == 0:
        other_n = 1
    else:
        other_n = 0
    if d[n][1] == 0:
        score1 = "love"
    else:
        score1 = str(d[n][1])
    if d[other_n][1] == 0:
        score2 = "love"
    else:
        score2 = str(d[other_n][1])
    talk(score1 + " " + score2)

def win(n):
    global first_server
    talk(d[n][0] + " wins the game")
    d[n][2] += 1
    d[0][1] = 0
    d[1][1] = 0
    deuce_mode = 0
    serve_turns = old_serve_turns
    if first_server == 0:
        first_server = 1
        current_server = 1
    else:
        first_server = 0
        current_server = 0
    if d[n][2] == match_points:
        talk(d[n][0] + " wins the match")
        d[0][2] = 0
        d[1][2] = 0

def add_score(n):
    global deuce_mode
    global current_server
    global serve_turns
    d[n][1] += 1
    if n == 0:
        other_n = 1
    else:
        other_n = 0
    if deuce_mode == 0:
        if d[0][1] == d[1][1] and d[0][1] == game_points - 1:
            deuce_mode = 1
            old_serve_turns = serve_turns
            serve_turns = 1
        if current_server == 0:
            print_score(0)
        else:
            print_score(1)
        if d[n][1] == game_points:
            win(n)
    else:
        if d[n][1] == d[other_n][1] + 2:
            if current_server == 0:
                print_score(0)
            else:
                print_score(1)
            win(n)
        else:
            if current_server == 0:
                print_score(0)
            else:
                print_score(1)
    if (d[0][1] + d[1][1]) % serve_turns == 0:
        if current_server == 0:
            current_server = 1
            talk(d[1][0] + " is serving next")
        else:
            current_server = 0
            talk(d[0][0] + " is serving next")

d = []
for i in xrange(2):
    d.append(["", 0, 0])
d[0][0] = "Player 1"
d[1][0] = "Player 2"
game_points = 11
match_points = 2
deuce_mode = 0
voice_mode = 1
serve_turns = 2
old_serve_turns = 2
current_server = 2
first_server = 0

talk("Ready to play")
while True:
    c = raw_input("Command: ").lower()
    if c == "z":
        if current_server != 2:
            add_score(0)
        else:
            talk(d[0][0] + " is serving first")
            current_server = 0
            first_server = 0
    elif c == "x":
        if current_server != 2:
            add_score(1)
        else:
            talk(d[1][0] + " is serving first")
            current_server = 1
            first_server = 1
    elif c == "1name":
        d[0][0] = raw_input("Player 1 name: ")
        talk("Welcome, " + d[0][0])
    elif c == "2name":
        d[1][0] = raw_input("Player 2 name: ")
        talk("Welcome, " + d[1][0])
    elif c == "gm":
        game_points = int(raw_input("Game points: "))
        match_points = int(raw_input("Match points: "))
    elif c == "s":
        serve_turns = int(raw_input("Serve turns: "))
    elif c == "togglevoice":
        if voice_mode == 0:
            voice_mode = 1
        else:
            voice_mode = 0
    elif c == "quit":
        quit()
    else:
        talk("Command not recognised")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Line by line analysis

```
import os
```

You need 2 blank lines before each global function definition.

```
def talk(n):
```

`n` is not descriptive and associated with a number. Don't use one letter variables unless it's really obvious (for example `i` loop counter, `k` and `v` as dict key and a value, or `d` as Twisted's deferred object. Something like `phrase` would be better.

```
    if voice_mode == 1:
```

Where does the `voice_mode` come from? Global variables are bad, pas it as a parameter to a `talk` method. Also, canonical way of checking if boolean is True is simply `if voice_mode`.

```
        os.system("espeak -ven+m3 '" + n + "' 2>/dev/null")
    else:
        print n

def print_score(n):
```

Again, `n` does not tell reader a lot.

```
    if n == 0:
        other_n = 1
```

What is `other_n`? If there's no better name for it - add a comment.

```
    else:
        other_n = 0
    if d[n][1] == 0:
```

Where did `d` come from? Pass it to a function. Also, better name.

```
        score1 = "love"
    else:
        score1 = str(d[n][1])
    if d[other_n][1] == 0:
        score2 = "love"
    else:
        score2 = str(d[other_n][1])
    talk(score1 + " " + score2)

def win(n):
```

Same thing with the `n` variable. Also, docstring might be helpful for this method.

```
    global first_server
```

Global variables are bad, really bad. Make your method take and return this if you need the variable.

```
    talk(d[n][0] + " wins the game")
```

This `d` is really quite obscure.

```
    d[n][2] += 1
    d[0][1] = 0
    d[1][1] = 0
    deuce_mode = 0
    serve_turns = old_serve_turns
    if first_server == 0:
        first_server = 1
        current_server = 1
    else:
        first_server = 0
        current_server = 0
    if d[n][2] == match_points:
        talk(d[n][0] + " wins the match")
        d[0][2] = 0
        d[1][2] = 0

def add_score(n):
```

Same thing: add docstring, replace `n` with better name and pass all the global variables as arguments to the function.

```
    global deuce_mode
    global current_server
    global serve_turns
    d[n][1] += 1
    if n == 0:
        other_n = 1
    else:
        other_n = 0
    if deuce_mode == 0:
        if d[0][1] == d[1][1] and d[0][1] == game_points - 1:
            deuce_mode = 1
            old_serve_turns = serve_turns
```

I don't see `old_serve_turns` used anywhere.

```
            serve_turns = 1
        if current_server == 0:
            print_score(0)
        else:
            print_score(1)
        if d[n][1] == game_points:
            win(n)
    else:
        if d[n][1] == d[other_n][1] + 2:
            if current_server == 0:
                print_score(0)
            else:
                print_score(1)
            win(n)
        else:
            if current_server == 0:
                print_score(0)
            else:
                print_score(1)
    if (d[0][1] + d[1][1]) % serve_turns == 0:
        if current_server == 0:
            current_server = 1
            talk(d[1][0] + " is serving next")
        else:
            current_server = 0
            talk(d[0][0] + " is serving next")

d = []
```

You need either a better data structure, or at least a good comment explained what the `d` is. Also, `d` needs a better name.

```
for i in xrange(2):
    d.append(["", 0, 0])
d[0][0] = "Player 1"
d[1][0] = "Player 2"
game_points = 11
match_points = 2
deuce_mode = 0
voice_mode = 1
serve_turns = 2
old_serve_turns = 2
current_server = 2
```

You only play with server 0 and 1, correct? Why do you need to obscure and add server 2 which is only there to start the game? Better have a flag of some sort.

```
first_server = 0

talk("Ready to play")
while True:
    c = raw_input("Command: ").lower()
```

Better name: `command`.

```
    if c == "z":
        if current_server != 2:
            add_score(0)
        else:
            talk(d[0][0] + " is serving first")
            current_server = 0
            first_server = 0
    elif c == "x":
        if current_server != 2:
            add_score(1)
        else:
            talk(d[1][0] + " is serving first")
            current_server = 1
            first_server = 1
    elif c == "1name":
        d[0][0] = raw_input("Player 1 name: ")
        talk("Welcome, " + d[0][0])
    elif c == "2name":
        d[1][0] = raw_input("Player 2 name: ")
        talk("Welcome, " + d[1][0])
    elif c == "gm":
        game_points = int(raw_input("Game points: "))
        match_points = int(raw_input("Match points: "))
    elif c == "s":
        serve_turns = int(raw_input("Serve turns: "))
    elif c == "togglevoice":
        if voice_mode == 0:
            voice_mode = 1
        else:
            voice_mode = 0
    elif c == "quit":
        quit()
    else:
        talk("Command not recognised")
```

Even though this if/else tree is acceptable in your scope, you might want to look into Strategy pattern. This is further reading though.

## Summary

Overall, your variable naming needs to be more readable. Don't use global variables, just pass the ones you need as arguments. For example, your `talk` function could be changed like this:

```
def talk(phrase, voice_mode=True):
    """Pronounce the phrase if the voice mode is on, otherwise print."""
    if voice_mode:
        os.system("espeak -ven+m3 '%s' 2>/dev/null" % phrase)
    else:
        print phrase
```

Don't forget to specify docstrings for non-trivial methods. Make them long if you need to. Use comments extensively to elaborate if variable name or a data structure is not descriptive enough.

Comment: Thanks! This was put together in a rush without much python experience. You really cleared some things up for me! The `d` array is for holding user data, such as `d[0][0]` holds Player 1's name and `d[1][1]` holds Player 2's score.

Comment: @NatZimmermann Might be better to name it `player_data` and turn it into a dict: `player_data = {'player1': {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 3}, 'player2': {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 8}}`. This is more explicit and lets you easier add additional parameters to the structure (if you decide to keep track of players' height for example).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll get to changing all the stuff now.

Comment: @NatZimmermann If you're interested - you can create another topic (don't adjust or edit this one) with your improved code and you might get higher level analysis (think design patterns).